# Merged two data sets by IDs, and now there are more observations

Tags: r, merge, duplicates, merging-data

R community. So I merged a csv "clin" with a csv "cpath" to create my dataframe "mint."
clin is 265 obs. of 62 variable.
cpath is 169 of 64 variables.
mint is 270 of 2 variables

I merged the csv files by the "kitid" variable (7 digit number); thus, each data row should have clin and cpath information for a specific kitid.
(kitid was named "kitid2" for cpath and "kitid" for clin to help with the merging function)

I searched for duplicates in kitid in each csv and in the "mint" dataframe, and there were none.

I did notice that when comparing the mint$kitid and mint$kitid2 columns, there was only one row in "mint" dataframe that had a kitid for cpath, but not clin. This would explain having 266 observations instead of 265, but there are still 4 data rows that have no explanation.

Does anyone have an idea of what the extra 4 data rows could be from? What could cause this?

Please help! Thank you to all!

Comment: try `sum(!clin$kitid %in% kitid$kitid2)` to see how many `kitid`s in `clin` aren't in `kitid` and vice versa (`sum(!kitid$kitid2 %in% clin$kitid)`). I'm guessing you have a couple observations in `cpath` that don't appear in `clin`

Comment: Also, I don't think there's any need to name the variable `kitid2`, right? If you're merging by that variable they can/maybe should both have the same name

Comment: 101 kitids are in clin that are not in cpath

Comment: It says that 5 kitids are in cpath that that are not in clin, which would explain the additional 5 data rows... this is interesting since when I viewed the columns side-by-side, I only saw one data row as such.

Comment: Please specify your question by inserting some codes and example. I guess dplyr would be a good package to solve your problem.